# Update Rows in Database with items from list, Python

Tags: python, list, updates

I am trying to update a field in a database, row by row, with a list of values. The following script works fine, but I can't help thinking there might be a more efficient (or pretty) way to update rows with items from a list. Here, I've just set a counter and updated the rows with the changing index item of the list.

```
listAreas = [1234.45, 3456.67, 6547.87, 536.76, 34.10]

indexIncr = 0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(databasePath, "ColumnName") as cursorArea:
    for rowArea in cursorArea:
        rowArea[0] = listAreas[indexIncr]
        cursorArea.updateRow(rowArea)
        indexIncr+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is more pretty, but this seems more pythonic to me.

```
for indexIncr, rowArea in enumerate(cursorArea):
    rowArea[0] = listAreas[indexIncr]
    cursorArea.updateRow(rowArea)
```

Comment: I knew I was looking for something just a little more simple and creative. I use enumerate all the time but today, my brain totally forgot about it. thanks for the suggestion. Nice one :)